# Limit the namespace from web url resource

Tags: kubernetes

According to the [ingress nginx controller doc](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#aws), it remind the object will use the ingress-nginx namespace, and can change to other namespace with `--watch-namespace` tag.

But when I using

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx0.28.0/deploy/static/provider/aws/service-l7.yaml --watch-namespace=default
```

It report

```
Error: unknown flag: --watch-namespace
See 'kubectl apply --help' for usage.
```

Answer (score 4):

You are messing up with one flag with others. By default following command will deploy the controller in `ingress-nginx` namespace. But you want it to be in some other namespace like `default`. To do so, you need to pass `kubectl`'s flag like `-n` or `--namespace`.

```sh
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx0.28.0/deploy/static/provider/aws/service-l7.yaml --namespace default
```

NB:

`--watch-namespace` is a flag of `nginx-ingress-controller`. It is used while running the binary inside the container. It needs to be set from `deployment.spec.contianers[].args[]`. It is used to bind the controller's watch in a single  k8s namespace(by default it watches objects of all namespaces).

Comment: is there a way not to choose a single namespace i want to see, but the opposite? Watch ALL other namespaces, except one?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set  `--watch-namespace` in the args section of nginx ingress controller deployment yaml

```
args:
  - /nginx-ingress-controller
  - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/$(NGINX_CONFIGMAP_NAME)
  - --tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/$(TCP_CONFIGMAP_NAME)
  - --udp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/$(UDP_CONFIGMAP_NAME)
  - --publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/$(SERVICE_NAME)
  - --annotations-prefix=nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
  - --watch-namespace=namespace
```

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/cloud-generic/deployment.yaml